# Complete drop in download speed when friend connected to wifi

Tags: wireless-networking

When my friend connects his laptop to my internet, my download speed goes from 2mb/s to 200kb/s (sometimes 0), and it only goes back to normal when my friend shuts off his wifi connection. he is wireless, i am on a custom build pc connected with an ethernet cord. i've searched it up numerous times, and only found a possible solution once, and that was to scan for malware and run tcpview and check for btdna.exe, which is supposedly related to torrenting, but he hasn't downloaded any of that type of stuff and scanning for malware or the task doesn't work. im at a complete loss, even asking in computer support discord servers doesn't help, they've never heard of the problem before. We are both on the most recent version of Windows 10, and I have switch wifi and routers many times but its stayed the same. as for checking rate-limit settings on my router, it doesn't appear to have any, but if all have it, then it should be off since i went through all of its settings and the closest thing i saw was media prioritization, which was off. and for ethernet connections, it still does the same

Comment: Have your friend run TCP/IP Reset. .......    Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer
See if that helps.

Comment: Please edit your question: This question really cannot be answered as posted since you are not providing details on what the make/model of the router is, what the make and model of the two PCs (devices?) are or what OS is running on these devices. Without these details this is just a very vague question.

Comment: Have you run Wireshark to determine what traffic is being generated between your friend's PC and the router?  Have you turned on Quality of Service (QoS) or rate-limiting on the router?  Does the same drop happen when your friend disables wifi and plugs into a second ethernet port on the router (probably yes)?

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to definitively answer without more information, but possibile cauaes include -

- An IP address conflict.
- Your friends computer is opening more simultaneous connections then your system.
- Your friends system is sending packets which mess with the server.
- Its unlikely but possible your router is misconfigured and is priotitisinghis traffix.

The "correct" way of diagnosing this is hard - you need to intercept or otherwise record the traffic to and from his computer (and yours) and analyse that.

One other "hail mary" thing to try is replacing your network cable and ensuring your network drivers are up to date.  It might be your network cable is failing but still working "well enough" but when the connection is shared that no longer happens.